# change file permissions recursively in Java?

Tags: java

Is there a way to change file permissions in Java recursively without walking the file tree or calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` ?

Comment: You could combine `java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree` with `java.nio.file.Files.setPosixFilePermissions`

Comment: @rkosegi Nice! This is definitely a more compact way than walk the file tree yourself. Thanks!